# Debian kernel update (Required for my wireless firmware to work) issues - unmet dependencies linux-base

Tags: debian, kernel

I am a first-timer user of linux, and I have been able to fix all issues I have met until this one.

Upon trying to upgrade the kernel version to something above 4.1 from Debian backport, I am met with the following message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64: Depends: linux-base  (>=4.3~) but 3.5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

scouring the internet has told me, that some users fixed it by doing a clean install from scratch, but I feel like I wouldn't learn anything from it, if it is fixable - and I have done 5 clean installs already since yesterday.

Comment: How are you trying to install the kernel? Did you download it manually, or are you using `apt-get`?

Comment: I followed this guide: https://wiki.debian.org/HowToUpgradeKernel.

Comment: Can't edit apparantly, and I pressed enter to quickly. I did it with apt-get.
I wouldn't know how to do it manually yet, some users have recommended compiling my own, but I feel already way more in above my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to upgrade to a backported kernel it to add Jessie backports to your repositories, if it's not already there:

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
```

(as `root`), then

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-amd64
```

will upgrade your kernel. Note that the kernels provided are now signed, which may cause issues if you're booting in BIOS compatibility mode; in that case, install [`linux-image-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64-unsigned`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/linux-image-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64-unsigned) instead:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64-unsigned
```

You might also need additional firmware; add `contrib` and `non-free`:

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
```

then

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-linux firmware-linux-nonfree firmware-iwlwifi
```

Enabling backports is safe: newer packages are not picked up automatically from backports, you need to explicitly select them using `-t jessie-backports` as above.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you have been so helpful!
After I installed the new kernel, I rebooted - it was stuck at a black screen, showed some greentext. After that the computer restarted and now it's at the black screen again with the white typer at the left corner.

Comment: @DannyDelic Disable the secure boot

Comment: @Stephen Kitt , The unmet dependencies  can be solved by installing the `linux-base` from backports . Why he need to install the `unsigned` kernel ?

Comment: In BIOS right? - Then I already have.

Comment: Booting into the old kernel still works though.

Comment: I managed to snap pictures of what happens during boot:

http://imgur.com/a/bu1od

Boot writes this to the screen, and then afterwards leaves it a blank black state.

Comment: Looks like you need to install firmware too; see my update.

Comment: It seemed to bypass most of the issues, but now I am met with the following message at boot.

    [    5.745988] Bluetooth: hci0: Setting Intel event mask failed (-16).

Most users who met this issue had no trouble booting into the system as far as I could tell by troubleshooting. Is there anyway I can just omit or remove anything bluetooth related, as I don't use it all?

Comment: To avoid initialising Bluetooth, try blacklisting the module: `echo blacklist bluetooth > /etc/modprobe.d/bluetooth-blacklist.conf`, then `update-initramfs -u`.

Comment: The issue stil persists? Any other hint?

Comment: These are my specs: http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/13-series/13-windows/

It says bluetooth 4.1 and wifi 8260 vPro, although the bluetooth is quite vague. Thanks a lot for the repeated help, but I am really clueless as to how I am supposed to approach this problem.

Comment: The fact that Bluetooth can't be initialised properly shouldn't prevent the system from booting... Are there any other error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You should install `linux-base` from backport to solve the dependencies problem:

```
sudo apt install -t jessie-backports linux-base
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, you have also been very helpful - I really appreciate the swift answers.